# Elasticsearch preserve_original parameter not working on pattern_replace token_filter

Tags: elasticsearch

trying to make a leading-zero-trimmer token filter like:

```
trimZero: {
  type: 'pattern_replace',
  preserve_original: true,
  pattern: '0*([1-9]+)',
  replacement: '$1'
}
```

Passing the input `abc 001`, I expect both outputs `abc 001` and `abc 1` from this token_filter since I have provided the option to preserve the original input, however I only see `abc 1`

Any idea why? and how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up preprocessing the input before passing it to elasticsearch.
so if given `abc 001`, it will become `abc 001,abc 1`

Then I created a custom tokenizer to split by `,`